# Restoring Ubuntu 12.04 to install state (or reinstalling without GRUB)

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2, uefi

I've been having issues with graphics card drivers that have gotten so complicated that I eventually have to completely reinstall Ubuntu to resolve them. However, due to my UEFI setup, the Ubuntu installer fails after it has already been installed once and leaves my GRUB install completely unusable (and sending me into grub rescue upon boot), and I have to do a total factory restore to be able to continue. This is not ideal, as I have to reinstall and set up everything on each OS I have in use.

How can I restore Ubuntu to the state that it was in upon install? If this is not possible, then how can I do a reinstall of Ubuntu over the same partition without reinstalling GRUB? Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: could you eleaborate a bit more on where the installer fails? at which point?

Comment: The installers fails upon trying to run the grub-install dummy.

Comment: do you have a file called sys/firmware/efi?

also, can you provide a screenshot or picture of your disk partitions?

Comment: I do have a folder named /sys/firmware/efi. It's contents are two folders, efivars and vars, as well as a systab file. 
It may also be important to note that I got this information (and the screenshot below) via live USB, as I can not start XOrg normally due to driver issues right now.

Comment: Here's my disk partition information (from both df in terminal, and gparted):
http://i.imgur.com/vlx3rHM.png

Comment: i assume that you chose sda8 as the point where you wished to re-install ubuntu?

also, i'd suggest that you go through this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: if that did not work, lemme know, i think there is another emthod that can work, which can be elaborated upon in chat.

Comment: Boot repair has given me the same issues before, halting on a GRUB install and causing it to start in grub rescue on boot.
Regardless, a fix may not be needed now. I was able to resolve the driver issues without a reinstall. The problem still exists, but it may simply not need fixing now. Thanks for the help regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that might help,

1.Mount your partition:

sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt   (X=whichever sda number you're using)
Bind mount some other necessary stuff:

for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt$i"; done
chroot into your Ubuntu install:

sudo chroot /mnt

2.Time to update grub:

update-grub

3.Depending on your situation, you might have to reinstall grub: //if you got errors in the previous step

grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub

If everything worked without errors, then you're all set:

exit

sudo reboot